# Программно изменить цвет в xml

Tags: android

Есть изображение круга в XML, SVG изображение. Я хочу сделать настройку цвета, для этого надо как-то программно его задавать. Как программно изменить цвет `android:strokeColor="#f5090d"`?

```
<vector android:height="11dp" android:viewportHeight="1280.0"
android:viewportWidth="1280.0" android:width="11dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#d1d1d1"
    android:pathData="M632.5,232.2c-4.4,0.4 -14.4,1.5 -22.2,2.3 -74.7,8.1 -148.7,40.1 -208.8,90.4 -11.6,9.7 -37,35.1 -46.6,46.6 -40.7,48.8 -69.5,106.3 -82.4,164.6 -14,63 -13.6,122.5 1.5,183.4 10.8,44.1 28.1,83.3 53.5,122 57.3,87.2 147.8,148.2 250.3,169 16.4,3.3 38.2,6.1 60.5,7.6 19.6,1.3 40.4,0.4 68.2,-3.1 113.2,-14.4 215.3,-78.1 278,-173.5 25.5,-38.8 42.7,-78.1 53.5,-122 16.7,-68 15.5,-136.8 -3.5,-203.1 -15.3,-53.3 -40.6,-100.6 -77.4,-144.9 -10.6,-12.9 -36.6,-38.3 -50.8,-49.9 -51.2,-41.8 -109.7,-69.6 -172.8,-82.1 -15.5,-3.1 -25.2,-4.4 -55.5,-7.4 -12,-1.3 -33.8,-1.2 -45.5,0.1z"
    android:strokeColor="#f5090d" android:strokeWidth="170"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. можно использовать библиотеку 
   https://github.com/devendroid/VectorChildFinder
2. можно создать несколько векторных изображений с разными цветами и менять их
3. можно нарисовать круг через shape и менять через GradientDrawable
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772537/i-need-to-change-the-stroke-color-to-a-user-defined-color-nothing-to-do-with-th